# How to install USB debug cable driver in WinDbg for Windows kernel debugging?

Tags: windows, drivers, debug

As per Microsoft's [USB debug page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-usb-3-0-debug-cable-connection), you must launch WinDbg in an elevated process in order to install the USB driver.

Having done that, I still receive this error message:

> Failed to copy USB device driver inf. The debugger must be run elevated for the first use of this transport. Error 0xE0000247.

Answer (score 1):

Just install last SDK official release version and that's all folks without other bcd options like "nosigning" and etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the right answer from here
[full details](https://www.ebay.com/itm/402650436755) or visit https://www.ebay.com/itm/402650436755

**3 Supported system OS**

From Win8 to Win10.

But home version OS is not very well supported at the debug machine(host PC side),because usb2dbg.sys maybe have a invalid signature(not all home version OS),it belongs to OS issue. But you can resolve
this issue by three ways:

a: change to other OS,eg:Enterprise Edition OS .

b: replace the unsignatured usb2dbg.sys file with signatured usb2dbg.sys file from Enterprise Edition OS .

c: Disable driver signature at the debug machine(host side),it mean the two side(host and salve) both disable driver signature.

Comment: Thank you for not only providing a link, but the textual context. I would be weary of treating an Ebay auction as a source of reputable information however. You are correct, the solution is to fix the improperly signed USB driver, which is what the other answers state.

Comment: You are welcome. 
Because the target group of our products is global, we need a variety of environments to test and reproduce customer problems, so we have experienced many difficulties in actual work.
I am happy ,I can hlep you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an unsigned USB debug driver eg: from preview build of WinDbg / driver tools for Windows SDK.

The error message is no doubt a catch all for "failed to install inf" for any reason. Not informative for those with non permission related failures (you correctly ran Windbg as Admin)

Solution: Reboot with "Disable Driver Signing Enforcement" eg: https://windowsreport.com/driver-signature-enforcement-windows-10/